# Gmail unread email count using curl

Tags: php, curl, xml-parsing, gmail, feed

I created a script that can get the unread email list as a feed from the Gmail.
Here is my code:

```php
<?php
//function to get unread emails taking username and password as parameters
function check_email($username, $password)
{ 
    //url to connect to
    $url = "https://mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom"; 

    // sendRequest 
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ":" . $password);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "");
    $curlData = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    //returning retrieved feed
    return $curlData;

}

//making page to behave like xml document to show feeds
header('Content-Type:text/xml; charset=UTF-8');
//calling function
$feed = check_email("username", "password");
echo $feed;
?>
```

The output getting like this:

```php
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<feed version="0.3" xmlns="http://purl.org/atom/ns#">
<title>Gmail - Inbox for example@gmail.com</title>
<tagline>New messages in your Gmail Inbox</tagline>
<fullcount>1282</fullcount>
<link rel="alternate" href="http://mail.google.com/mail" type="text/html" />
<modified>2012-08-01T12:33:48Z</modified>
<entry>
<title>eBCS Pro 1 August 2012</title>
<summary>bcs logo eBCS Pro 1 August 2012 Video interview Olympic IT The Met Police&#39;s director of IT, Steve</summary>
<link rel="alternate" href="http://mail.google.com/mail?account_id=test@gmail.com&amp;message_id=138e21a3404cc7b2&amp;view=conv&amp;extsrc=atom" type="text/html" />
<modified>2012-08-01T12:12:44Z</modified>
<issued>2012-08-01T12:12:44Z</issued>
<id>tag:gmail.google.com,2004:1409100718455703474</id>
<author>
<name>eBCS Newsletter</name>
<email>e-bullefdgfdtin@dgdg.uk</email>
</author>
</entry>
<entry>
```

I want to read the:

```php
<fullcount>1282</fullcount>
```

tag

When you pass the username and password to this function, it can show the email list.
I need to get only the message count.
Is there any way to catch or count the items?

Comment: No I don't. That's the reason I'm looking forward to it

Comment: Dont' suppose anyone knows if it's possible to get the full body of the email and not just a summary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is the answer, i read the xml tag using php

```
$xmlobjc = new SimpleXMLElement($feed);

echo $xmlobjc->fullcount[0];
```

and replace the header with

```
header('Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8');
```

Answer (score 0):

This works too:

```
curl -u $(cat username):$(cat password) --silent 'https://mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom' | sed -n 's:.*<fullcount>\(.*\)</fullcount>.*:\1:p'
```